# How do i change the Permissions of my home folder?

Tags: permissions, administrator

I am the only **administrative** user of my computer, for some reason it tells me that I am **not** the admin, even though i am **logged in as the admin user**??? 
I recently clicked on my home folder's permissions and **it says "The permissions of "constantin" could not be determined."** What the heck is going on here? is this some kind of bug? Its very frustrating!!!

Comment: check your username is it in root group or not ?

Comment: How many admin accounts do you have.

Answer (score 2):

Reading your question, it seems like perhaps you might have accidentally deleted your user entry from either `/etc/group` or `/etc/password` and thus part of the permissions have been lost, leaving nautilus unable to determine them. Or you simply changed the permissions of your home directory itself to not be readable.

If you run `ls -lhd /home/constantin` in a terminal, what is the output?

You may need to run `sudo chmod ug+rwx /home/constantin` in the terminal as well, so that nautilus will be able to see the permissions again.

Comment: "1s command not found" is what i get after typing that in...and nothing happens when i type in the sudo command...should i be typing in something before writing 1s -1hd /home/constantin ?

Comment: that's an L (`l`) not a 1 (`1`)

Comment: oh, haha...fail, bare with me im a noob! here is what i got drwxrxr- x 43 constantin constantin 4.0k the date and time /home/constantin

Comment: Well, you probably successfully ran the sudo command before. It doesn't print any results. Does nautilus now show the correct permissions when you look at the properties of that folder?

Comment: No it doesnt it still says that they can not be determined

Comment: I tried the chmod a=r testfile to wipe the permissions so i can readd them, but it tells me that there is no such directory...do you guys recommend that i reformat my disk and reinstall? i never touched any files but i have a feeling something somehow got erased..any opinions?

Comment: Your home directory itself has the correct permissions. I have no idea why nautilus is giving you that message based on any information here.

Comment: Ever since I installed Ubuntu it has been acting buggy, I've had it for about a week now. The home folder windows will all close at random, sometimes applications wont load, and this entire situation is happening. Do you think it might all be related?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe you have bad hardware. But this isn't really the best place to go about debugging that.

Comment: I ended up re installing, Im working on a mac mini and after doing some research ive found that its not recommended to work of a mac since they tend to not like it when their users tinker